# Installation problem for Tensorflow with conda

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda3

I am getting this error while using 'conda install tensorflow' to install tensorflow on Anaconda

> CondaVerificationError: The package for tensorflow-base located at 
>   'Lib/site-packages/tensorflow-2.1.0.data/purelib/tensorflow_core/include/tensorflow_core/core/grappler/optimizers/generic_layout_optimizer_transposer_factory.h'specified
>   in the package manifest cannot be found.

Any Help will  be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Can you precise which OS are you using ?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the tensorflow and install  it again :

Try this:

```
pip install tensorflow #CPU only
pip install tensorflow-gpu #For GPU support
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Comment: Thanks @marton I have done that but i am now getting this error                                    
ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/noarch::keras-preprocessing-1.1.0-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/__pycache__/text.cpython-37.pyc'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.

Comment: should tensorflow be uninstalled with `conda uninstall tensorflow` or `conda remove tensorflow`?